# Choosing power unit

Tags: desktop-computer

Maybe, this is enough simple question for knowing people, so sorry for asking. I configured a PC for my friend, which specs are given below. Will 500W power unit be enough for it, or I should change it?

Thanks

Specs:
Intel Core i5-9400F

MSI B360 Gaming Plus

Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2060 OC 6144MB

HyperX DDR4 16GB (2x8GB) 3200Mhz Fury Black

Kingston SSDNow A400 TLC 480GB 2.5"

Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 64MB 3.5"

Be Quiet Pure Rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PC Part Picker, the estimated wattage for this system is 346W. You will have enough headroom with a 500W PSU.

Worth noting though:

> Some Intel B360 chipset motherboards may need a BIOS update prior to using Coffee Lake Refresh CPUs. Upgrading the BIOS may require a different CPU that is supported by older BIOS revisions